# How can I convert jekyll files to something that is easily accessible such as pdf

Tags: pdf, converters, jekyll

I want to convert jekyll files to a pdf/html or something that can be accessed easily without having to install any software / dependencies that I don't really use in daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [jekyll-pandoc-multiple-formats](https://github.com/fauno/jekyll-pandoc-multiple-formats).

I've personal had never had any success using it, but I do use the jekyll-pandoc for website

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of your goal, but assuming you have jekyll installed, you could always run `jekyll serve` and use a browser extension like [this](https://getfireshot.com/) that has the ability to capture a screenshot of the entire webpage and save it as a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll does not require you to install any software to access the site. A Jekyll isntallation generates a _site folder. The contents in this folder are plain HTML and CSS. They are portable and offline accessible. Just copy this folder to your USB disk and take it with you. Jekyll IS the converter you are looking for.